# Underlying probability space for a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I took a rigorous course on probability theory last semester, and am taking a much less theoretical course on stochastic processes now and was thinking about how some of the concepts translate over. In particular, I wanted to know how to specify an underlying probability space for a discrete, time-homogenous Markov chain with state space $\cal{S} = \{ 1, 2, \cdots, n \}$, an initial probability vector $\pi_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and transition matrix $P$. I'll describe a construction I came up with.

First, define a sequence of probability spaces $\{ \left( \Omega_n, \cal{F}_n , \textbf{P}_n \right) \}_{n = 0}^\infty$, where $\Omega_n = \cal{S}$ and $\cal{F}_n = \mathcal{P} \left( \cal{S} \right)$ for all $n \ge 0$. The probability distirbution $\textbf{P}_n : \cal{F}_n \to [0, 1]$ is defined by the probability vector $\pi_n := \pi P^n$ in the obvious way where the entries of $\pi_n$  determine the probabilities on each singleton of $\cal{F}_n$.

I thought a natural choice for a sample space $\Omega$ for the Markov chain would be the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0} \to \cal{S}$. We can define for each $n \ge 0$ the evaluation map $X_n : \Omega \to \Omega_n$, defined on each $\omega : \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0} \to \mathcal{S}$ in $\Omega$ by $X_n(\omega) = \omega(n)$. Then we generate a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ from the preimages of all the $X_n$
$$\mathcal{F} = \sigma \{ X_n^{-1} \left( \{ k \} \right) \subseteq \Omega \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}, k \in \cal{S} \}$$

Now to define $\textbf{P} : \cal{F} \to [0, 1]$. For each event $\{ X_n = k\} := X_n^{-1} \left( \{ k \} \right) \in \mathcal{F}$, set
$$\textbf{P} \left( \{ X_n = k\} \right) := \textbf{P}_n \left( \{ k \} \right)$$

If everything so far is sound, my question is on how can to extent $\textbf{P}$ to a probability on the whole of $\mathcal{F}$ (if such an extension even exists)? I feel that this is most likely done using the Carathéodery extension theroem by first somehow extending to the algebra generated by the events $\{  X_n = k \}_{k \in \mathcal{S}, n \ge 0}$. I'm guessing we can maybe define for finite intersections using the transition matrix $P$ by
$$\textbf{P} \left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^N \{ X_{n_i} = k_i \} \right) := \textbf{P} \left( \{ X_{n_1} = k_1 \} \right) \prod_{i = 1}^{N - 1} P_{k_i, k_{i + 1}}^{n_{i + 1} - n_i}$$
for $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_N$, and then extend to finite unions by inclusion-exclusion, but beyond that I'm completely lost.

If my construction is hopelessly flawed and doomed to fail, I'd appreciate if someone could explain the proper way to specify the underlying probability space of a Markov chain anyways.

Comment: Not a real answer, but I recommend to read chapter IV, section 4 ('Construction of Probability Spaces') in 'Probability and Stochastics' (Çinlar 2011).

Answer (score 1):

The construction you are looking for is described in Theorem 3.4.1 of Meyn and Tweedie's book (*Markov chains and stochastic stability*), although they don't get into the details of the proof. A full proof appears in Theorem 2.8 and Proposition 2.10 of Revuz's book (*Markov Chains*, 1984 edition).